# Listing coordinates of polygons in WKT format

Tags: arcpy, well-known-text

I have a polygon shapefile made up of 2 shapes (independent of each other). I'm using the code below to print in the ArcMap python console, a list of each shapes coordinates in WKT format. I get an error though.

```
Feature 0:
Part 0:
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'X'
```

What am I missing? 'Williamson_Tunnels_Alert_Zone' is the name of the feature in question by the way.

```
import arcpy

infc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Enter for loop for each feature
#
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Williamson_Tunnels_Alert_Zone", ["OID@", "SHAPE@WKT"]):
    # Print the current multipoint's ID
    #
    print("Feature {0}:".format(row[0]))
    partnum = 0

    # Step through each part of the feature
    #
    for part in row[1]:
        # Print the part number
        #
        print("Part {0}:".format(partnum))

        # Step through each vertex in the feature
        #
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt:
                # Print x,y coordinates of current point
                #
                print("{0}, {1}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y))
            else:
                # If pnt is None, this represents an interior ring
                #
                print("Interior Ring:")
        partnum += 1
```

Comment: Your row[1] is a WKT string not a geometry object. Either just `print row[1]` or use the search cursor to access the `shape@` geometry object instead of the `shape@wkt` WKT string. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the [data access cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) `"SHAPE@"` token and the `"SHAPE@WKT"` token. The `"SHAPE@"` token returns a [geometry object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm) with parts, etc. The token `"SHAPE@WKT"`returns a string of the feature's geometry in WKT format.

From the help:

> SHAPE@WKT —The well-known text (WKT) representation for OGC geometry.
>   It provides a portable representation of a geometry value as a text
>   string.
>
> SHAPE@ —A [geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm) object for the feature.

So use:

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Williamson_Tunnels_Alert_Zone", ["OID@", "SHAPE@WKT"]):
    print("Feature {0}:".format(row[0]))
    print (row [1]) #wkt string
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that short 3 line code was all I needed! I'm a bit of a noob still with python so this will help me learn.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is

```
print("{0}, {1}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y))
```

`pnt` is a Unicode String and it doesn't have an attribute called `X` (or probably `Y` either).

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the environmental workspace somewhere else in this code not shown for the Williamson_Tunnels_Alert_Zone layer?  If not your cursor statement needs to reference the infc layer:

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@WKT"]):
```